# Hyperledger Fabric port 7053

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In the Hyperledger Fabric peer definition, we map ports 7051 and 7053. I understand that 7051 is used for connecting the peer, and it is also used by the peers for gossiping. The port 7052 is used for chaincode connections. However, I am not sure about the use of port 7053. Can anyone please describe it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Port `7053` is the default port for the event hub service which can be used by client to subscribe to block and chaincode events.  In Fabric v1.0 it was also the only mechanism used by the various client SDKs for checking the status of a transaction submitted by the client.

In Fabric v1.1 and v1.2, the event hub still exists (but it is going away in Fabric v1.3) but has been superseded by a channel-based event service which uses the same port--`7051`-- as other peer services.  See http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/peer_event_services.html?highlight=channel%20event%20service for additional information on this service.

Comment: Hey @Gari, can you explain where the 7052 port works and how It's used?

Comment: 7052 is the default port used for chaincode containers to communicate with the peer.  If you do not explicitly set `peer.chaincodeListenAddress`, then the peer will listen on port 7052 using the same IP/host that you set for `peer.address`.